# Type hints for asyncio's Process class

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm trying to type hint the `Process` class returned by `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()` but am getting a weak warning (Accessing a protected member of a class or a module inspection) in PyCharm, using Python 3.10 as interpreter.

My code:

```py
from asyncio.subprocess import Process
...
self.process: Process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    *run_cmd,
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

What is the Pythonic way of resolving this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because for some strange reason the `Process` class is not included in the [`asyncio.subprocess.__all__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/asyncio/subprocess.py#L1) list.

When a module defines a specific [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) list and you import names from that module that do not appear in that list, PyCharm issues a warning because it considers that to be similar to importing *protected* names (starting with one underscore `_`).

Since [PY-8656](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8656) PyCharm supports the `noqa` directives used by [`flake8`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html#in-line-ignoring-errors) to exclude a line from linter checks.

Therefore the simplest solution is to just add such a directive to the import line:

```py
from asyncio.subprocess import Process  # noqa

process: Process
...
```

This has no impact on the type hints with `Process`. It is still recognized as a type by any type checker and its (public) methods are still exposed and known.

Comment: I bet it's not in `__all__`, because it's not intended for direct instantiation and is mostly useful as a type hint.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Maybe. But I don't think so. It is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.subprocess.Process) like a regular class and it is not even mentioned anywhere that it should not be directly instantiated. Moreover, if you use the lower-level API, it could even be useful to _subclass_ it. I honestly do not see a reason to exclude it from `__all__`, even _if_ the maintainers intended it to be used just as a type hint. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: Hm, okay, subclassing certainly makes sense. Then what do you think  - is it worth an issue on python github?

Comment: I thought about it, but this is such a minor issue and there is so much more important stuff to do, I would not want to clutter up the issues. Not to mention, all linters I have tried (`flake8`, `pylint`, `ruff` etc.) do **not** issue a warning/error for an import of something that is not in `__all__`. Only PyCharm warns about this, as far as I can see. If anything, I would argue PyCharm is overly cautious here. Realistically, the only relevance of `__all__` is for `*`-imports anyway. Not for marking something as public/protected.